# Ember store find() - use ID from server response instead of whatever you pass to find function

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

Whenever I call `this.store.find('campaign', url)`, if the entry is not found in store it makes a request to API  and creates a record in that store with ID being `url`. I need to be able to make sure that the record that is being pushed to the store uses `id` from the payload that is returned by API and not `url` that I pass in to `find()` function. What's the best way to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

Override `extractId()` of your serializer, whether it's a [RESTSerializer](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#method_extractId) or [JSONSerializer](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.JSONSerializer.html#method_extractId).

Comment: doesn't seem like it's working... here is my code, nothing gets outputted. What version of Ember has this been added to? I'm using 1.12. `export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  extractId: function (model, hash) {
    console.log(model);
    console.log(hash);
    return this._super(model, hash);
  }
});`

Comment: so it seems lie what I said is correct... I guess I need to use either `extractFind` or `extractSingle` but I can't figure out how to override it. I tried something like `extractSingle: function(store, type, payload, id) {
    id = payload.campaign.id;
    return this._super(store, type, payload, id);
  }` but no success

Comment: You aere right... I cannot find `extractId()` in Ember-data 1.13 for RESTSerializer. I had an idea of overriding `find()` but I don't think it would help neither. What would it be like if you used `queryRecord('campaign', { id: url})` instead of `find()`?

Comment: well queryRecord is also the new API, I would normally use something like `find('campaign', {url: 'test'})` and internally it would call `findQuery` adapter... I tried that but it expects an array I believe and API returns a single record.